# How to batch query by an array in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I have a table `Thread`:

```
{
  userId: String
  messageId: String
}
```

Now I have an array of `userIds`, I need to query 20 messageIds for each of them, I can do it with a loop:

```
const messageIds = {}
for (const userId of userIds) {
  const results = await Thread.find({ userId }).sort({ _id: -1 }).limit(20).exec()
  messageIds[userId] = results.map(result => result.messageId)
}
```

But of course this doesn't perform well. Is there a better solution?

Comment: You can use the `$in` operator in your find query, so it will check each of the values in userIds

Comment: @Nicolas I think you didn't understand my question, the problem is the `limit` part.

Comment: Can you explain more ?

Comment: @Nicolas It's in the question: _I need to query 20 messageIds for each of them_

Comment: So the $in operator is made for that. Be I do not understand the problem. You want to query wich message is attached tu an userID ?

Comment: What is the average number of messages for each user?

Comment: @hyades It varies, from 10 - 10000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your approach is that you are issuing multiple separate queries to MongoDB.

The simplest workaround to this is using the `$push` and `$slice` approach. But this has the problem that the intermediate step would creating an array of huge size.

Another way could be to use `$facet` as part of aggregation query.

So you need a `$facet` step in the aggregation like -

```
[
{$facet: {
    'userId1': [
        {$match: {userId: 'userId1'} }, 
        {$limit: 20}, 
        {$group: {_id: '', msg: {$push: '$messageId'} } }
        ],
     'userId2': [
        {$match: {userId: 'userId2'} }, 
        {$limit: 20}, 
        {$group: {_id: '', msg: {$push: '$messageId'} } }
        ],
        .... (for each userId in array)
    }}
]
```

You can easily just generate this query by iterating over the list of users and adding keys for each user.

So you end up with an object where key is the `userId` and the value is the array of messages (`obj[userId].msg`)

Comment: The exact performance might depend on a lot of factors. But this approach surely avoids multiple trips to the mongodb server and theoretically should be faster.

Comment: I've tried this answer, it works, but it doesn't seem to be able to use index

Comment: Just saw the result of the `explain`. It seems what you say is correct (https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-30474). Your best bet would be to use your original method till this is issue is open.

Comment: thanks for the link, it mentioned the method of adding a `$match` outside `$facet`, would it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation to group threads by userId, and return the top 20:

```
db.threads.aggregate([
    {$match: {userId:{$in: userIds}}},
    {$sort: {_id: -1}},
    {$group: {_id: "$userId", threads: {$push: "$$ROOT"}}},
    {$project: {_id:0, userId:"$_id", threads: {$slice:["$threads", 20]}}}
])
```